# How to implement BFCP for screensharing using SIP

Tags: asterisk, sip, freeswitch

I need to implement a screen sharing application using BFCP but not able to find much, can some one please describe or explain in brief how this can be achieved. There is very little information about this on the internet now sure why. SO doesnot even have a tag for **BFCP**

I have gone through the following links from [cisco](https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/12627756/understanding-binary-floor-control-protocol-bfcp-wireshark-packet-captures) and also found an outdated [library](http://confiance.sourceforge.net/bfcp) for implementing it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Is there any other way for sharing screen in a video SIP call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sip support multiple streams. Number of SDP streams is unlimited, both end should support new one.

Fore sure no problem send screen sharing info as video stream and send any special info related(like mouse move etc) by SIPMESSAGE. However such setup will require SIP expert in team.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please also tell if there is any way of implementing the BFCP protocol?

Comment: Sure there are alot of ways, but that is task for team and not for asterisk(PBX).